# Assessment of air-tightness of windows

Tags: windows

I am in the US. I need an independent assessment of  air-tightness of windows. Whom should I hire to do that?

Comment: Meh, the latest obsession is to make houses *too* airtight.  Then you need more forced circulation (which costs energy) and active systems to assure *enough* air gets changed (to avoid poisoning the occupants with CO2 buildup).  Spending good money and energy to do what an old Victorian does naturally, and you have to go pay to live in a hotel when the power fails.  SMH.

Comment: This is not a question of energy saving. In my case residue accumulates inside which makes it hard to see anything through a window.

Comment: Pardon my rant.  Residue accumulating is *itself* profoundly disturbing.  What prevents it from also accumulating in your lungs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look for a "home energy auditor" or an "energy efficiency auditor" in your area.

For air-tightness, they'll typcically do a [blower door test](http://www.energy.gov/energysaver/blower-door-tests), which basically uses a huge fan to slightly pressurize the interior of the house v. the outside air pressure.  Then they go around and check for pressure leaks.  Locally, our electrical utility will help you arrange energy audits (and will sometimes offer rebates, etc.).  That may be another avenue to check if you have trouble locating a professional in your area.